# How to partially overwrite blob in an sqlite3 db in python via SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, blob

I'm having a db that contains a blob column with the binary representation as follows

[image: blob as displayed by DB Browser]

The value that I'm interested in is encoded as little endian unsigned long long (8 byte) value in the marked. Reading this value works fine like this

```py
p = session.query(Properties).filter((Properties.object_id==1817012) & (Properties.name.like("%OwnerUniqueID"))).one()
id = unpack("<Q", p.value[-8:])[0]
```

id in the above example is 1657266.
Now what I would like to do is the reverse. I have the row object p, I have a number in decimal format (using the same 1657266 for testing purposes) and I want to write that number in little endian format to those same 8 byte.
I've been trying to do so via SQL statement

```sql
UPDATE properties SET value = (SELECT substr(value, 1, length(value)-8) || x'b249190000000000' FROM properties WHERE object_id=1817012 AND name LIKE '%OwnerUniqueID%') WHERE object_id=1817012 AND name LIKE '%OwnerUniqueID%'
```

But when I do it like that I then can't read it anymore. At least not with SQLAlchemy. When I try the same code as above, I get the error message `Could not decode to UTF-8 column 'properties_value' with text '☻'` so it looks like it's written in a different format.
Interestingly using a normal select statement in DB Browser still works fine and the blob is still displayed exactly as in the screenshot above.
Now ideally I'd like to be able to write just those 8 bytes using the SQLAlchemy ORM but I'd settle for a raw SQL statement if that's what it takes.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work with SQLAlchemy by basically reversing the process that I used to read it. In hindsight using the + to concatenate and the [:-8] to slice the correct part seems pretty obvious.

```py
p = session.query(Properties).filter((Properties.object_id==1817012) & (Properties.name.like("%OwnerUniqueID"))).one()
p.value = p.value[:-8] + pack("<Q", 1657266)
```

By turning on ECHO for SQLAlchemy I got the following raw SQL statement:

```
UPDATE properties SET value=? WHERE properties.object_id = ? AND properties.name = ?
(<memory at 0x000001B93A266A00>, 1817012, 'BP_ThrallComponent_C.OwnerUniqueID')
```

Which is not particularly helpful if you want to do the same thing manually I suppose.

It's worth noting that the raw SQL statement in my question not only works as far as reading it with the DB Browers is concerned but also with the game client that uses the db in question. It's only SQLAlchemy that seems to have troubles, trying to decode it as UTF-8 it seems.